# Allow only the registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I create a method that will navigate the visitors to a registration path before (s)he signs in or signs up?

Comment: Are you using any gem for authentication, like devise or authlogic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a before_filter on your controllers to ensure that users are signed in, with the default action of redirect to registration if they are not.

There is a Gem called Devise which is very useful for authentication and is well worth the effort of learning it.

Another good place to go is http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

This will give you an excellent grounding in Rails